# Digital I/O using the MSP-EXP430FR6989

Tags: msp430, ti-ccstudio

The problem I am trying to solve is: Write a program which controls 8 LEDs connected to Port 2 of the MSP430.
A momentary switch (push button) should be connected to Port 1.5
When the button is pressed, the LEDs should form an 8-bit binary counter counting from 00h to FFh
and then back to 00h.
When the button is not pressed, the LEDs should be animated so that the light sweeps from side to
side.
I have written the following program so far:

```
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; MSP430 Assembler Code Template for use with TI Code Composer Studio
;
;
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .cdecls C,LIST,"msp430.h"       ; Include device header file
            
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .def    RESET                   ; Export program entry-point to
                                            ; make it known to linker.
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .text                           ; Assemble into program memory.
            .retain                         ; Override ELF conditional linking
                                            ; and retain current section.
            .retainrefs                     ; And retain any sections that have
                                            ; references to current section.

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESET       mov.w   #__STACK_END,SP         ; Initialize stackpointer
StopWDT     mov.w   #WDTPW|WDTHOLD,&WDTCTL  ; Stop watchdog timer


;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Main loop here
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mov.b #00h, P1SEL0
    mov.b #00h, P1SEL1
    mov.b #0FFh - 1<<5, P1DIR
    mov.b #BIT5, P1REN
    clr.b P1OUT

    mov.b #00h, P2SEL0
    mov.b #00h, P2SEL1
    mov.b #0FFh, P2DIR
    clr.b P2OUT

MainLoop:
    ; Check if the push button is pressed
    bit.b #BIT5, &P1IN             ; Check P1.5
    jz ButtonPressed               ; If button is pressed, jump to ButtonPressed

    ; If button is not pressed, animate LEDs sweeping from side to side
    mov.b #1, R6                    ; Start with LED pattern 00000001
    mov.b #P2OUT, R5                ; Load Port 2 output address

SweepLoop:
    mov.b R6, &R5                   ; Output LED pattern to Port 2
    rra.b R6                        ; Rotate LED pattern right
    jnz SweepLoop                   ; Continue sweeping until all LEDs are lit

    mov.b #0x80, R6                 ; Reset LED pattern to start from the other side

SweepBackLoop:
    mov.b R6, &R5                   ; Output LED pattern to Port 2
    rra.b R6                        ; Rotate LED pattern left
    jnz SweepBackLoop               ; Continue sweeping until all LEDs are lit

    jmp MainLoop                    ; Repeat the main loop

ButtonPressed:
    ; If button is pressed, count in binary from 00h to FFh and then back to 00h
    mov.b #0, R7                    ; Initialize counter

BinaryCounterLoop:
    mov.b R7, &R5                   ; Output counter value to LEDs
    inc.b R7                         ; Increment counter
    cmp.b #0xFF, R7                 ; Compare counter value with FFh
    jne BinaryCounterLoop           ; If not FFh, continue counting

    mov.b #0, R7                    ; Reset counter to 00h

BinaryCounterBackLoop:
    mov.b R7, &R5                   ; Output counter value to LEDs
    inc.b R7                        ; Increment counter
    jnz BinaryCounterBackLoop       ; Continue counting until counter overflows and becomes 00h

    jmp MainLoop                    ; Repeat the main loop
                                            

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Stack Pointer definition
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .global __STACK_END
            .sect   .stack
            
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Interrupt Vectors
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            .sect   ".reset"                ; MSP430 RESET Vector
            .short  RESET
```

This program is TI Code Composer studio Empty assembly-only project using the MSP-EXP430FR6989. The only code I wrote is inside the "Main loop here" section. I am having trouble getting the leds on my breadboard connected to the MSP to do the sweeping motion. Whenever I run the code, it runs until I get to "BinaryCounterLoop" and will do the counter and change the leds to match, but cant get it to do the sweeping motion when button isnt pressed. I have uploaded a picture of my breadboard with 8 leds, 8 resistors, and a button.

[image: Breadboard connected to MSP430]

The 8 leds are connected to pins 2.0-2.7 and the button is connected to pin 1.5. Please help me understand why it's not working and how to fix it.

Comment: Does the program have to be written in assembler, or are you able to use C?